# A way to include android libraries in react native code

Tags: android, sdk, react-native, android-library

I have built an Android library that works perfectly fine with Android Applications when used as an AAR in an Android Studio project. Is it possible to use this same library in a React Native environment? If not, will it take a lot of effort to make this library compatible with React Native?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library to create library for React Native [`react-native-create-library`](https://github.com/frostney/react-native-create-library)
or

the official way to integrate Native Modules which will be found in
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android

Answer (score 0):

My answer is yes, it's possible, the android folder in react-native project is actually an android project, you can integrate a AAR lib here, make a function to invoke them, and call this function in `.js` file